# crontab printing script instead of executing it

Tags: php, cron

here my problem width crontab:
I need to run a php script everyday at noon and so on my crontab i set:

```
# 0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php -c /var/www/fanta-trade/operazioni_pianificate_medaglie.php > /var/www/cron_log

0 12 * * * root  /usr/bin/php /var/www/offertegaseluce/operazioni_pianificate.php > /var/www/offertegaseluce/cron_log

*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/fanta-trade/operazioni_pianificate_ordini.php > /var/www/cron_log

#20 */6 * * * /root/certs/certbot-auto renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade
```

the line that i need is actually the second... i tried many debugging:

I checked the timezone and it is properly set to europe-rome

I checked width whereis the position of php and /usr/bin/php is correct

I tryed to run the script as root or just widthout user specification
    0 12 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/offertegaseluce/operazioni_pianificate.php > /var/www/offertegaseluce/cron_log

I checked if crontab as a sevice is running and restarted it

I checked if the script itself is reacheable and if it works and if i call the script via browser it works

but actually crontab is not executing the script it just copy paste the cript itself to the log file

any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: what is the content on `operazioni_pianificate_ordini.php` ? try some simple php script there like `echo 'Testing cronjob';`

Comment: Have you tried without > /var/logfile ? The output will anyway go to syslog

Comment: try to use no shorttags in your script , e.g. use <?PHP

Comment: If you can run the same line "/usr/bin/php /var/www/offertegaseluce/operazioni_pianificate.php" then you know that the problem isn't user specific.  Running the script in the browser runs with user www-data

Comment: nuwan, how the content of the scrip might change the crontab? @fatfreddy i tried nut nothing changed